# ListView with custom Adapter does not show all item seperator between different listItems

Tags: android, user-interface, listview

I developed small application .It contain a `ListView` in `Dialog` box .

I tested my application it work just fine all emulator except in a emulators with specification qvga 240*320 and wqvga432 in that Item separator are not shown all in ListView!.

I added

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="6" />`

layout of item in listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"

  >
  <TextView
    android:layout_height="60dip"

    android:id="@+id/ThemeLabel"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 

    android:paddingRight="50dip"
    android:paddingLeft="20dip"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:text="Theme 7" 
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="20dip">
  </TextView>

  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"

    android:layout_margin="3dip"
    android:id="@+id/ThemeIcon"
    android:background="@drawable/icon"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ThemeLabel"

  >
  </ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

tag in the manifest file
And tested in samasung Galaxy 3 ,I got same  result

Any Help will be highly appreciated

thanks in advance

Regards,kariyachan

Answer (score 1):

My be you have targetted android min version to 3 in the manifest. Try changing it to 4. I had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like a problem to me.
are you sure its not shown?
or is it like the screen becomes so small that you can't see it clearly?
no offend intended, but since im also testing my listview on 2.5 inches screen and its not creating a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the replay .yes iam sure,got a problem on samsung galaxy 3.it does not show some Item seperators in a list view